# Find the value of $z-y.$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
 y \\
 z
\end{pmatrix}$, $y,z \in \mathbb R$ be the eigenvector to a real eigenvalue of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &2 \\
 1& 0 & -4 \\
 0 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$ then $ − $ is equal to____

My attempt:-

Since, $\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
 y \\
 z
\end{pmatrix}$, $y,z \in \mathbb R$ be the eigenvector to a real eigenvalue of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &2 \\
 1& 0 & -4 \\
 0 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$. Then $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &2 \\
 1& 0 & -4 \\
 0 & 1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
 y \\
 z
\end{pmatrix}=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
 y \\
 z
\end{pmatrix}\implies$. $\begin{pmatrix}
2z \\
2-4z \\
 y+3z
\end{pmatrix}=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
 y \\
 z
\end{pmatrix}$. I am not able to conclude $z-y$ from this.

Comment: Hint: The last equation implies $z=\lambda$

Comment: I did, I got $y=\lambda^2-3\lambda$

Comment: So, $z-y=-(\lambda^2+4\lambda)$

Comment: But answer given is 3.

Comment: yes. sorry.Now, I can do it. Thank you very much

Comment: I got $\lambda=1$ and $z-y=-5$ :(

Comment: Double-check your arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you very much